# Pythonic way to flatten a dictionary into a list using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following function:

```
def create_list_from_dict1(mydict):
    output = []
    for k, v in openint_dict.items():
        output.append( (k, v['field1'], v['field2'], v['field3']) )

    return output
```

Essentially, it flattens the dictionary, so that I can perform sorting on one of the fields of the tuple in the returned list.

I don't like the fact that I am having to 'hard code' the field names of the value dictionary (`'field1'`, ..., `'fieldN'`), and I want a more pythonic and elegant way of doing this so that this function works for all dictionaries that contain a fixed structure (non-nested) dictionary as its values.

I imagine that I will have to use `**kwargs` and/or a `lambda` function, as well as list comprehension. What would be the most pythonic way to write this function?

Comment: So you start with a dictionary of dictionaries? Does the order within the tuple matter? Do they need to be consistent between the tuples, even? Are the keys you're extracting values for a subset of the keys in the `v` dictionaries, or all of them? Could you give an example input and acceptable output? (Sorry for long comment!)

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Answers given in same order as questions: Yes, Yes, Yes, No - the keys are ticker codes, and the tuples consist of market data

Comment: Could you edit the question accordingly, and add an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
fields = ("field1", "field2", "field3")

output = [[k] + [mydict[k].get(x) for x in fields] for k in mydict]
```

In that code we iterate dict keys and add them with selected subset of second-level dictionaries values.

Comment: I would replace the hard coded fields with a call to `mydict.keys()`.  Otherwise, it seems very elegant, and just what I'm looking to do. Will try it out first though ... to make sure it works, before accepting your answer.

Comment: Take a note that dictionary in python is not ordered, so using `mydict.keys` you mix your data.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli that will give you the keys to the *outer* dictionary, too, which may not be the same as the inner dictionaries (still no example?)

Comment: Yes, I thought we talking about inner dictionaries, because fields hardcoded  for them.

Answer (score 4):

This *might* solve your problem:

```
def create_list_from_dict1(mydict):
    return [
        (key,) + tuple(v for _, v in sorted(val.items()))
        for key, val in sorted(mydict.items())
    ]
```

This assumes that:

- You want the same order for the values in each tuple in the output;
- You want the outer and inner keys sorted alphabetically (otherwise you'll need an appropriate `key` for `sorted`);
- You want the values for all of the keys from the inner dictionaries; and
- All of the dictionaries in the input contain all of the same keys (otherwise you'll get more/fewer entries in each tuple, and no guarantee they're aligned).

Note the use of `.items` in both inner and outer loops to sort both by key (two-tuples are sorted on the first element, with the second only used to break ties) and the conventional `_` identifier for *"we won't be using this any more"*.

In use:

```
>>> create_list_from_dict1({
    'hello': {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2, 'baz': 3},
    'world': {'foo': 4, 'bar': 5, 'baz': 6},
})
[('hello', 2, 3, 1), ('world', 5, 6, 4)]
```

Comment: Can you explain this: `tuple(v for _,` ? I have never come across this syntax before ... it looks like you're invoking a magic method.. what does the underscore mean?

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli per the answer, `_` means *"we aren't using this"* (the inner dict's key, in this case). It's like `... for k, v in ...` but makes it clearer that `k` is being ignored on purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think I will go with your answer, as its the most pythonic. However, I may have to sub class the dict class, with my own class which will have a fields attribute to use in the function, instead of calling `sorted(val.items())`. The tuples are records from a database, so the order of the columns must not be changed.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli then are you sure you have the right data structure to begin with?

Comment: Absolutely, the data is coming from a database.

Answer (score 0):

If order doesn't matter...

```
def create_list_from_dict1(mydict):
    output = []
    for k, v in openint_dict.items():
        fields = [value for key, value in v.items()]
        output.append( tuple([k] + fields )

    return output
```

If order matters you either need to do as you did and call out the fields specifically...or you need to used an `OrderedDict` for the sub-dicts.

Answer (score 0):

Python `dict`s have `keys()` and `values()` methods to get a list of the keys and values. If order of the fields is not important:

```
[(k,) + tuple(v.values()) for k, v in mydict]
```

If the ordering of the values does matter:

```
[(k,) + tuple([v[i] for i in sorted(v.keys())]) for k, v in mydict]
```

Note that the second option would be identical to the first without the call to `sorted()`. The order depends on how things were added to the subdict, so you should use the second option as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_list_from_dict1(mydict):
    return [tuple([k]+list(v.values())) for k,v in openint_dict.items()]
```

doesn't use the fields' names and produces the same result.

In Python 3.5,  you can just type (because starred expressions are allowed everywhere):

```
def create_list_from_dict1(mydict):
    return [(k,*v.values()) for k,v in openint_dict.items()]
```

Comment: The problem with this is that there's no guarantee that `values` from each inner dictionary will be in the same order, which the OP commented as a requirement.

Comment: Not sure, but  it seems to work on a 'fixed structure'. I don't know if is garanteed.

Comment: It isn't guaranteed, that's what I'm telling you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be pythonic:

```
[(k, v) for k, v in dict_data.items()]
```